# RelativeLayout между двумя view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

**Цель:**

Рут элемент в разметке - RelativeLayout.

Есть header(допустим RelativeLayout) с фиксированной высотой, который прижат к верху рут элемента с помощью

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Есть footer(допустим LinearLayout) с фиксированной высотой, который прижат к низу рут элемента с помощью

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Есть RelativeLayout(обозвем его content), в котором есть несколько TextView, HorizontalScrollView, LinearLayout.

Мне нужно, чтобы этот RelativeLayout(content) размещался между header'ом и footer'ом.

При этом нужно чтобы компоненты внутри RelativeLayout(content) сжимались/расширялись в зависимости от свободного пространства и заполняли всю среднюю часть рут-элемента.

В RelativeLayout(content) должны быть три горизонтальных скролла, в которые динамически добавятся ImageView.

**Как я сейчас пытаюсь реализовать:**

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_layout_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Some Text 111"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hs1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hs1"
            android:text="Some Text 222"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hs2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv2">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hs2"
            android:text="Some Text 333"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hs3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv3">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот так добавляю ImageView в LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setId(i);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 8, 0);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.cow));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            layout1.addView(imageView);
        }
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Как добиться желаемого результата ? Чтобы скролл с картинками
   уменьшался/увеличивался и вписывался между хедером и футером ?
2. Возможно у меня не правильный подход в целом ?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

т.к. у вас все элементы идут один под другим, то

1. вместо `RelativeLaout` лучше использовать `LinearLayout` c `android:orientation="vertical"`
2. Так вам даже не понадобится внутренний "content" `RelativeLaout` использовать.
3. Для того, чтобы элементы в середине занимали всю доступную высоту надо проставить им "веса" равные друг другу, а высоту раную нулю. Так они займут всю высоту поровну, не считая высоты, занятой элементами с конкретно заданными высотами.

Таким образом разметка должна быть примерно такой:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:text="Some Text 111"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hs1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dip">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:text="Some Text 222"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hs2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dip">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:text="Some Text 333"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hs3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dip">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="ЗАДАЙТЕ_КОНКРЕТНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ТУТ"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы очень помогли!

Comment: @researcher, пожалуйста)

Comment: На самом деле большое спасибо! Очень много разных вариантов пробовал, но никак не мог добиться нужного. Спасибо!

Comment: Юрий, картинки, которые загружаю в LinearLayout, сплющиваются по высоте, а по ширине нет. Можно это как-то исправить ?

Comment: @researcher, это из-за атрибута внутренних линеаров у скроллов (`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`) поставьте `match_parent` и поиграйтесь со значениями `scaleType` для `ImageView`

Comment: Спасибо Вам еще раз! scaleType=CENTER_INSIDE решил вопрос!

Comment: Атрибут android:weight="1" не существует, а внутри RelativeLayout атрибут android:layout_weight не имеет смысла.

Comment: @CoolMind, это был лишь набросок разметки, но я исправил